# Meaning of "the flap-handled"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The air shimmered with warmth. The table, large, wooden, scarred, was laid
> at one end with a bleached cotton cloth, a pile of bowls, a fistful of spoons.
> All the objects in the room looked like cartoons of themselves: **the flap-handled
> fridge**, the brown piano grinning, the dresser where plates leaned
> and cups hung.

Does the phrase in bold mean: the fridge that its handle is hung?

Source: The Children's Bach by Helen Garner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some doors on refrigerators ('fridges') and freezers are opened by a handle with a flap. To open the door, the fingers are used to pull the flap towards you; this unlatches the door and you can now pull the flap more to make the door swing open.

[image]